# java - detect mouseReleased without mousePressed

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have a MouseListener on a component and want to listen to mouseReleased events, without needing mousePressed events.  How can I detect if the user presses on another button, the desktop, or other window, (or anything, really) and releases on my component?

For instance, in the following example, how can I get it to print "cool", instead of "Not cool"?

```
titleBar.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("cool");//Detect this
    }
    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.print("Not ");//Without this having to happen first
    }
    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: By doing `// System.out.print("Not ");`

Comment: No, I meant that the mouseReleased event is only called after mousePressed.  How do I detect a release without a press on my button in question?

Comment: How can a release occur without a press?

Comment: A press on any other button or component would be fine, but how do I detect that they move the mouse and release on my button?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think it is one of these zen sentences, in the tune of "how does a tree falling sound if there is nobody to hear it". :-D

Comment: I think you want to differentiate between normal Clicked events and Pressing on a button releasing on another. Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't listen for a mouseReleased when the mousePressed originated on another application. This is because the Java application will not have focus when the mouse is released. Java con only handle events when it has focus.

Within a Java application you can listen for all mouseReleased events. However, in this case the mouseReleased event will be generated for the component that generated the mousePressed event. So you will need to also listen for mouseEntered and mouseExited events. So if a mouseReleased event is preceded by a mouseEntered event you would need to use the source of the mouseEntered event to get the object for the mouseReleased event.

For this you can use the AWTEventListener. See [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Java Components can detect MouseEvents when the mouse cursor is within the Component's bounds; although the application window may still be in focus during ( ie. window resizing via drag-n-drop ) MouseEvents are no longer notified to the application window Component even if it is a MouseListener, since the mouse cursor is outside of the Component's bounds.